# Initializing const struct instances with pointers to each other

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

In a C++ program, I have a struct that contains a pointer to another instance of its own type:

```
struct Foo
{
  const Foo* ptr;
};
```

I want to declare and initialize two const instances of this struct that point to each other:

```
const Foo f1 = {&f2};
const Foo f2 = {&f1};
```

However, this results in the compile-time error `error: 'f2' was not declared in this scope` (obviously because f2 is declared after f1, even though f1's declaration references it).

Is what I'm trying to do possible and reasonable? If it is, how do I make it work?

One workaround might be to avoid making f1 const, then reassign the pointer after f2 has been declared (`f1.ptr = &f2;`), but I'd rather avoid this if I can.

Answer (score 6):

At namespace scope you can do e.g.

```
namespace my_constants {
    extern Foo const f1;
    extern Foo const f2;

    Foo const f1 { &f2 };
    Foo const f2 { &f1 };
}  // namespace my_constants
```

---

I can's see any really good solution for local scope, but you *can* in principle do

```
auto hack = []( Foo const* pfoo ) -> Foo const&
{
    static Foo const other = {pfoo};
    return other;
};

static Foo const    f1{ &hack( &f1 ) };
Foo const&          f2 = hack( 0 );
```

Comment: don't even need the `extern Foo const f1;` !

Comment: Actually, it looks like I don't even need the namespace, do I?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that my struct definition and instance declarations are in the global scope, so it seems to work if I just add `extern Foo const f2;` before declaring f1.

Comment: +1 for that aweful hack.  As an aside, it makes `f2` effectively `static`!  You could really solve this with some `optional` trickery, so long as you can access the ptr-to before construction.

Answer (score 3):

You can put them both inside another `struct`.

```
struct Foo
{
  const Foo* ptr;
};

struct interlinked_foos {
  Foo a = { & b }; // An initializer may forward-reference a class member.
  Foo b = { & a };
} twofoos;

const Foo & f1 = twofoos.a;
const Foo & f2 = twofoos.b;
```

This is C++11. In C++03, it seems you would need to add a constructor to `Foo` but the principle still works.

Not only doesn't it require an object to be `extern`, this potentially encapsulates the pattern for reuse.

**Edit:** Here's a terser, but slightly less elegant version (it assumes the objects are the same type):

```
const Foo twofoos[] = { & twofoos[1], & twofoos[0] },
          & f1 = twofoos[0], & f2 = twofoos[1];
```